# How can you use selectors that match multiple nodes via jsdom/jquery in node.js?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have a very simple example thus far, I'm basically trying to rip the path to a logo from a website dynamically.

```
var sys     = require("sys"),
request = require("request"),
$  = require("jquery"),
uri     = 'http://www.stevelacey.net';

request({uri:uri}, function (error, response, context) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log($("#logo img", context).attr('src'))
  }
})
```

This works fine until I expand on the selector:

```
console.log($("#logo img, #links a img", context).attr('src'))
```

Which then returns:

```
Object [ jsdom NodeList ]: contains 5 items has no method 'indexOf'
```

Obviously, because the selector matches more than one element; this happens as soon as you try to select this way, not even trying to use the results incorrectly i.e. setting attr on a NodeList. Either way, jQuery deals with this gracefully in the browser.

My question is is this a limitation of jsdom or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug, digging around in the source and changing:

```
 var this_index = smallest_common_ancestor.childNodes.indexOf( this )
 var other_index = smallest_common_ancestor.childNodes.indexOf( otherNode )
```

on line `114` in `jsdom/level3/core.js` to:

```
 var this_index = smallest_common_ancestor._childArray.indexOf( this )
 var other_index = smallest_common_ancestor._childArray.indexOf( otherNode )
```

Successfully returns "images/header.png" (I suppose that was what you expected it to return).

`this` and `otherNode` are both objects. `childNodes` is also an object, so there's no `indexOf`, `_childArray` on the other side seems to contain the same stuff but as the name already suggest it's an array.

I'd suggest you to file a bug on this so they get it fixed:
https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues

(Note: there is a [Pull request](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/pull/162) with a patch pending)

Comment: I believe this has now been fixed.